# How to get three or more column averages in another column in iReport?

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports

I have a Jasper report like the one below...

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 51 | 52 |
| 51 | 52 | 53 |

I want the below...

| column1 | column2 | column3 | average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 51 | 52 | 51 |
| 50 | 51 | 52 | 52 |

I'm using Postgresql, is it possible to get the average value in the query part?

Comment: You mean like `SELECT column1, column2, column3, (column1 + column2 + column3) / 3 AS average FROM report`?

Comment: @Bergi...little difference if  one or two column have null value then average value column will get wrong data ...?

Comment: You could divide by [`num_nonnulls`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-FUNC-TABLE) instead… or you just write a subquery that selects the `avg()` from some `values`.